# Advanced search in Apple Notes

Tags: notes.app

I have about 10k notes in Apple Notes on my MacBook and I was wondering if there is a way just to search for titles, instead of the note contents?

In earlier versions of the program the results were sorted so that title results came first, but this seems to be no longer the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly awkward solution, but it might work with a bit of tweaking: a *shortcuts* workflow that asks for a text (or gets it when started via context-menu etc.) and uses the appropriate `search notes`. action.

You should be able to load my action via https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/d72c594e1617429a9c3dbae1ea682289. If not, just recreate it as shown in the screenshot. The dialog on the bottom is the result list shown after the search (I searched for `in`). [image: Screenshot of shortcut]

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this would work! I'll install Monterey soon and give it a try. (I'd give you a +1 but I don't have enough reputation yet.)

Comment: I've had another idea: If you lock notes, only the title is visible and can be searched. (yes, this might be even clunkier than the previous idea)

Answer (score 0):

I find that if you type in the search word or phrase you are after then write ‘in title’ it seems to work

Comment: That must be a coincidence - I still get hits where the word doesn't appear in the title.